# AWS account delineation for hosting multiple customers servers

Tags: amazon-web-services

We host our clients' infrastructure. We are looking at AWS for some services. However, our business model is to provide the hosting included in our fee so to that end we need to be the account holder. We therefore need to have one account which is billed but clear delineation between different separate client infrastructure. Ideally with a separate console etc. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at consolidated billing, as it sounds like it will meet your needs:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/consolidatedbilling.html

This would enable you to set up unique "linked accounts" per customer, each fully separate and independent of each other (separate console logins, separate security configurations, etc.).